# Get sum only if no other related entries in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following result returned with the following query in SQL Server 2005.. Now, I want to add a business rule. If the partnumber has a plant associated with it, and it is not the plant I am not currently checking, it should list as zero.

For xample, in the following result, the plant-partnumber combination 96-ABC should return the sum as zero. But the 11-DEF combination should continue to display as 50. And all other values should return the same result as of now.

How to modify the query for this? Though I tried hours, I have not reached a solution.

**Explanation**: For the highlighted row below, the partnumber is ABC. But the part has no relationship with plant "96", as you can see the data in MHL and MMHP tables…   (This is similar to DEF scenario)…. But the partnumber has association with other `plants` (20 and 21)– hence the part has `restricted association`  and it should show as **zero** for plant "96"…. Whereas for DEF part, it is `OPEN association`  with all plants - hence the sum of all line items should be the SumQty (i.e, 50 as displayed now)

Note: Can we get it in a single query? Splitting into two query and doing an update will not work for me.

**Current Result**

[image]

**DATA**

```
DECLARE @MHL TABLE (LineNumber VarCHAR(5), PartNumber VARCHAR(10), Qty INT)


INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10001','ABC',10)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10002','ABC',100)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10003','DEF',50)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10005','KXY',25)
INSERT INTO @MHL VALUES ('10006','KXY',30)


DECLARE @MHP TABLE (PlantCode VarCHAR(5), LineNumber VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('20','10001')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('21','10002')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('80','10005')
INSERT INTO @MHP VALUES ('80','10006')


DECLARE @MasterPLantParts TABLE (PlantCode VarCHAR(5), PartNumber VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('20','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('21','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('96','ABC')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('11','DEF')
INSERT INTO @MasterPLantParts VALUES ('80','KXY')
```

**SELECT QUERY**

```
select 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  sum(MHL.Qty) as SumQty
from @MasterPLantParts mpp
left outer join @MHP MHP 
    on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
inner join @MHL MHL 
    on (
        MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber 
        or (
             mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber
             and MHP.LineNumber is null
            )
        )
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
```

Comment: I don't understand why 96-ABC should return as 0 and the rest of the entries should display the sumqty. I guess I don't understand what "it is not the plant I am not currently checking" means. Can you clarify the general rule for why 96-ABC shouldn't display?

Comment: yea, I think from this logic 20-ABC and 21-ABC should be 0 too.

Comment: what about 21-ABC ? chould display 0 ?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd... ABC has a restricted association with plant 21. And it should show as 100 as it is displayed now.

Comment: +1 for good question (the data creation script helps people with access to Sql Server).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you want, you need to do it in steps...

```
select mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber PartNumber, sum(IsNull(mhl.Qty,0)) as Qty
into #tt
from @MasterPLantParts mpp
left join @MHP MHP on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
left join @MHL mhl on (mhl.PartNumber = mpp.PartNumber and mhl.LineNumber = mhp.LineNumber)
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber


update tt
set Qty = mhl.Qty
FROM #tt tt
inner join @MHL mhl on (mhl.PartNumber = tt.PartNumber)
where tt.Qty=0
  and not exists (select 1 from @MasterPLantParts mpp where mpp.PlantCode<>tt.PlantCode and mpp.PartNumber=tt.PartNumber)

select * from #tt
drop table #tt
```

This produces...

```
PlantCode PartNumber SumQty
20        ABC         10
21        ABC         100
96        ABC         0
11        DEF         50
80        KXY         55
```

As a single select statement this can be done as follows...

```
select mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber PartNumber, Sum(case mhl2.RecCount
                                                                when 1 then mhl2.Qty
                                                                ELSE IsNull(mhl.Qty,0) END) as Qty
from @MasterPLantParts mpp
left join @MHP MHP on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
left join @MHL mhl on (mhl.PartNumber = mpp.PartNumber and mhl.LineNumber = mhp.LineNumber)
left join (select PartNumber, count(1) RecCount, Sum(Qty) as Qty
            from @MHL
            group by PartNumber
            having count(1)=1) mhl2 on (mhl2.PartNumber = mpp.PartNumber)
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
```

Comment: Thanks.. But can we get it in a single query? Splitting into two query and doing an update may not work for me..

Comment: You could always put it in a view and do a select on the view.

Comment: I've added single select version of my solution

Answer (score 1):

The following query would get you the desired result. First, all rows from MasterPLantParts are selected (using a LEFT OUTER JOIN). Then, a join is made with MHL. If there were no entries in MHP for a given Plant, then all Lines from MHL are selected for the Plant).

An additional LEFT OUTER JOIN (mhl_parts) is made with distinct Parts that are available in MHP. If a Part is not available in MHP at all, then the sum is calculated from MHL for all Lines. Otherwise, it would be zero.

```
select 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  sum(case
      when (MHP.LineNumber is null and mhl_parts.PartNumber is null) or 
        (MHP.LineNumber is not null and mhl_parts.PartNumber is not null)
      then MHL.Qty
      else 0
  end) SumQty
from MasterPLantParts mpp
left outer join MHP on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
left outer join
(
  select DISTINCT MHL.PartNumber PartNumber
  from MHL
  INNER JOIN MHP ON MHP.LineNumber = MHL.LineNumber
) mhl_parts
on mhl_parts.PartNumber = mpp.PartNumber
inner join MHL on MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber or (mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber and MHP.LineNumber is null)
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c284/25)</kbd>

**Oracle 8i syntax**:

```
select 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  sum(case
      when (MHP.LineNumber is null and mhl_parts.PartNumber is null) or 
        (MHP.LineNumber is not null and mhl_parts.PartNumber is not null)
      then MHL.Qty
      else 0
  end) SumQty
from MasterPLantParts mpp, MHP, MHL,
    (
      select DISTINCT MHL.PartNumber PartNumber
      from MHL
      INNER JOIN MHP ON MHP.LineNumber = MHL.LineNumber
    ) mhl_parts
where mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode(+)
and mpp.PartNumber = mhl_parts.PartNumber(+)
and (MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber or (mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber and MHP.LineNumber is null))
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is in one query.
I changed logic of this.

First I collect data from MHP and MHL tables, count sum of data.

And after that just join them.

```
;WITH twoInOne AS (

    SELECT MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber, SUM(MHL.Qty) AS Qty
    FROM @MHL AS MHL
    LEFT JOIN @MHP AS MHP
        ON MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber 
    GROUP BY MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber

)
SELECT 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  CASE 
    WHEN tIO.PlantCode IS NOT NULL THEN tIO.Qty
    WHEN tIO2.PlantCode IS NULL AND tIO2.PartNumber IS NOT NULL THEN tIO2.Qty
    ELSE 0
 END
FROM @MasterPLantParts mpp
LEFT JOIN twoInOne AS tIO
    ON mpp.PlantCode = tIO.PlantCode
    AND tIO.PlantCode IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN twoInOne AS tIO2
    ON mpp.PartNumber = tIO2.PartNumber
    AND tIO2.PlantCode IS NULL  
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
```

I don't know Oracle, but I guess can be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
  mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
  CASE 
    WHEN tIO.PlantCode IS NOT NULL THEN tIO.Qty
    WHEN tIO2.PlantCode IS NULL AND tIO2.PartNumber IS NOT NULL THEN tIO2.Qty
    ELSE 0
 END
FROM @MasterPLantParts mpp, 
    (SELECT MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber, SUM(MHL.Qty) AS Qty
    FROM @MHL MHL, @MHP MHP
    WHERE MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber(+)
    GROUP BY MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber
    ) tIO,
    (SELECT MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber, SUM(MHL.Qty) AS Qty
    FROM @MHL MHL, @MHP MHP
    WHERE MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber(+)
    GROUP BY MHP.PlantCode, MHL.PartNumber
    ) tIO2
WHERE mpp.PlantCode = tIO.PlantCode(+)
    AND mpp.PartNumber = tIO2.PartNumber(+)
    AND tIO.PlantCode IS NOT NULL
    AND tIO2.PlantCode IS NULL  
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post a Oracle8i version also?

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but looking at some examples below added it.

Answer (score -2):

warning: untested, might not be efficient either - sqlfiddle is not working

```
select mpp.PlantCode PlantCode, 
    mpp.PartNumber PartNumber,
    nvl(sum(MHL.Qty),0) as SumQty -- edit1: add nvl
from @MasterPLantParts mpp
left outer join @MHP MHP on mpp.PlantCode = MHP.PlantCode
left join @MHL MHL on (  -- edit2: from inner join to left join
        MHL.LineNumber = MHP.LineNumber 
    or (
        mpp.PartNumber = MHL.PartNumber
        and mpp.PartNumber not in ( 
            select MHL2.PartNumber 
            from @MHL MHL2 
            inner join @MHP mhp2 on MHL2.LineNumber = MHP2.LineNumber 
            where mhp2.PlantCode != mpp.PlantCode 
        )
    )
)
group by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
order by mpp.PlantCode, mpp.PartNumber
```

Comment: Not returning data for plant 96

Comment: Can you please update the answer with correct result? If not can you please delete the post? Having an upvoted answer that doesn't meet the requirement is confusing...

Comment: when you said "not returning data for plant 96" did you mean there is no row for plant 96 or value for plant 96 is null? I assumed it was the latter.
btw: can we move to chat for further conversation?

Comment: Thanks to 3 anonymous samaritans for down-voting my answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c284d/8 -- replaced NVL that doesn't exists in SQL Server to COALESCE.